# how to tokenize string with split() in java?

Tags: java, string, tokenize

I need to tokenize this string.

```
AddItem rt456 4  12 BOOK "File Structures" "Addison-Wesley" "Michael Folk"
```

I need

```
"AddItem","rt456","12","BOOK","File Structures","Addison-Wesley","Michael Folk"
```

substrings. How i can get these tokens with using split()?

Comment: Really, `split`? Why you want to complicate your life? Wouldn't simple Pattern/Matcher be simpler? You can also write your own simple parser for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([^\"]\\S*|\".+?\")\\s*").matcher(str);
while (m.find())
    list.add(m.group(1));
```

Output:

```
[AddItem, rt456, 4, 12, BOOK, "File Structures", "Addison-Wesley", "Michael Folk"]
```

Comment: @user3460845: Use `replaceAll("\"", "");`